# Why OnGroupClick redraws the ExpandableList

Tags: android, expandablelistview, selecteditem

I am new to Android.

I have a `ExpandableListView`, where I have managed to highlight (persistent) the selected item/child. But when I click/touch the group,  the highlighted item goes away and seems like list has been redrawn. In `onGroupClick`, I am try to keep the highlighted item highlighted, but even then it redraws the list.

```
    @Override
public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, long id) {
    // TODO keepSelectedModuleHighlited. Right now its not working.
    if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
        parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
    } else {
        parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
    }

    keepSelectedModuleHighlited();

    return true;
}
```

And method : keepSelectedModuleHighlited

```
    private void keepSelectedModuleHighlited() {
    if (lastSelectedView != null && lastSelectedDrawble != null) {
        lastSelectedView.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.module_selected));
    }

}
```

How can I put my method just after it redraws the list? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since when Android "redraws the list", it calls `getChildView()` on your `ExpandableListAdapter`, you need to put your highlighting code in `getChildView()`.